# magnific popup issues: cannot find indexof

Tags: jquery, sitecore, magnific-popup

I am trying to use a this magnific popup and can't seem to get it to work. I need it to pull up an iframe ( which only works by going to you-tube instead of using the magnific popup ). So I thought I'd at least just use a test of an image to see if it works and I'm getting the error of "cannot find indexOf". I am using Sitecore to grab the images and am wondering if that is what is creating this issue.

HTML

```
<div class="videoContainer" >
    <sc:Link ID="videoLink" Field="Video Link" runat="server">
        <div class="videoLink"><sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="Video" runat="server" /></div>
    </sc:Link>
</div>
```

JS

```
//open image
$('.videoLink').magnificPopup({
    disableOn: 768,
    type: 'image',
    removalDelay: 160,
    image: { verticalFit: true }
});
```

The rendered HTML is

```
<div class="videoContainer" >
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/video...">
        <div class="videoLink"><img src="/~/media..."></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I thought if I could get the image working first, then the video might work but so far I'm getting that error. I tried using .videoContainer as the click but getting same thing, don't think its finding anything there when it actually is.

Comment: You're calling `magnificPopup` on a div, not on a link. Have you tried `$('.videoLink').parent().magnificPopup(...)`?

Comment: for crying out loud I tried this earlier and it didn't work, but then I fixed the other issue and forgot to go back to this as a solution and now it does lol, thanks

Comment: No problem :) comment converted into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `magnificPopup` on a div, not on a link.

Change your code to:

```
$('.videoLink').parent().magnificPopup(...)
```